# How to not reuse a UIContentViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I tried using a `nil` reuse identifier.

```
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:nil forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Yet I got this error:

```
 'must pass a valid reuse identifier to -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
```

Comment: There's not a single good reason to avoid reusing reusable UI objects.

Comment: Now that I've looked into it, I agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to reuse cells (which is a VERY BAD IDEA, cell reuse is there for a reason!), you need to just create the cells:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init:...];
```

Comment: How to I get the cell's frame?

Comment: The cell's frame in the collection view? `[self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame` should work. Or if you just want the width/height, `cell.frame.size.(width/height)` is fine.

Comment: The same way you get the frame of any other `UIView` subclass.